# How to configure URL redirect with WildFly/JBOSS 16? (Rewrite rules), 404 "Not Found" error with deployed Angular app

Tags: angular, wildfly

I'm serving my Angular application using **WildFly 16**. After I put the war in the deployment and try to access the app, it works as expected, however every time I manually refresh the page (i.e. F5) I got a Not Found message.

1. I've been looking a lot of sites and most of them are not specific enough or use older versions of WildFly.
2. I heard about Handlers and Predicates attributes but I don't know how or where to use them (http://undertow.io/undertow-docs/undertow-docs-1.2.0/predicates-attributes-handlers.html)
3. I think should be similar than Apache Rewrite rules https://www.stefanoscerra.it/apache-rewrite-rules-configuration-for-angular/
4. Hash Location strategy doesn't work in this case because I need the URL "clean" for some redirection from a 3rd party app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up updating the web.xml file inside the war everytime I make the build. I added the **error-page** section

```
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
<display-name>Spotlight</display-name>
<welcome-file-list><welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file></welcome-file-list>
<error-page>
<error-code>404</error-code>
<location>/</location>
</error-page>
</web-app>
```

Comment: Search the whole internet for this solution. Thank you!