# Fallback configuration on Wildfly to index.html for a war-packaged Angular application

Tags: angular, wildfly, war

I build my angular 9 application as a war file for an easy deployment on wildfly 19.

The problem is that i need to fallback to index.html for deep link requests (e.g.  "http://www.example.com/heroes/42") as described in the angular documentation for server deployments

https://angular.io/guide/deployment#routed-apps-must-fallback-to-indexhtml

I tried to achieve this via the following entry in a created **undertow-handlers.conf** file

```
not file(%U) -> redirect('/index.html')
```

Does anybody know how to configure this for a war deployment for wildfly?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to configure URL redirect with WildFly/JBOSS 16? (Rewrite rules), 404 "Not Found" error with deployed Angular app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55481874/how-to-configure-url-redirect-with-wildfly-jboss-16-rewrite-rules-404-not-f)

Comment: that works perfectly! thanks!